# JQuery file upload (RailsCasts #383): Upload multiple resolutions to S3

Tags: jquery-file-upload, railscasts

I am using the upload_helper described in RailsCasts episode #383 to directly upload files to AWS S3.

The following works for me, the image is re-sized to 800x600 and stored to S3.

```
jQuery ->
  $('#fileupload').fileupload
    processQueue: [
      {
        action: 'loadImage'
        fileTypes: /^image\/(gif|jpeg|png)$/
        maxFileSize: 20000000
      }
      {
        action: 'resizeImage'
        maxWidth: 800
        maxHeight: 600
      }
      { action: 'saveImage' }
    ]
   add: (e, data) ->
    $.blueimp.fileupload.prototype.options.add.call(this, e, data)
```

Now, what I want to do is also store a much smaller version as a thumbnail. I have the following code which seems to be working apart from the fact that its trying to upload both files to S3 using the same POST request.

```
$.blueimp.fileupload::processActions.duplicateImage = (data, options) ->
  if data.canvas
    data.files.push data.files[data.index]
  data

jQuery ->
  $('#fileupload').fileupload
    processQueue: [
      {
        action: 'loadImage'
        fileTypes: /^image\/(gif|jpeg|png)$/
        maxFileSize: 20000000
      }
      {
        action: 'resizeImage'
        maxWidth: 800
        maxHeight: 600
      }
      { action: 'saveImage' }
      { action: 'duplicateImage' }
      {
          action: 'resizeImage'
          maxWidth: 400
          maxHeight: 300
      }
      {action: 'saveImage'}
    ]
    add: (e, data) ->
      $.blueimp.fileupload.prototype.options.add.call(this, e, data);
```

The error I am getting is as follows.

POST https://mybucket-uploads.s3.amazonaws.com/ 400 (Bad Request)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>InvalidArgument</Code><Message>POST requires exactly one file upload per request.</Message><ArgumentName>file</ArgumentName><ArgumentValue>2</ArgumentValue><RequestId>F2D33882A6556810</RequestId><HostId>3DP7aHL4aR1ErG5eIWh2kgQUXbsrytBU2u/pdQO746X2njjWckUVZtivcIJoY9qYsOBN13TPbyU=</HostId></Error>
```

How can I get this to work?

Comment: Hi, I ran into the same issue, have you ever found a solution?